# Do multiple "Give you more on recall knowledge checks" feats stack?

Tags: feats, skills, pathfinder-2e, stacking

I've seen at least 2 feats with different names that have the exact same effect, although one has more fluff (that you can easily get on the same character, as one is a dedication and the other is a class feat):
[know it all](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=197) and [font of knowledge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1133)

Both grant:

> When you succeed at a Knowledge check, you gain additional information or context. When you critically succeed at a Knowledge check, at the GM’s discretion you might gain even more additional information or context than normal.

By RAW,  would these stack and give you two pieces of additional information/context,  or is it considered just granting the same benefit twice to no effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## These May Be Duplicate Effects (So No)

The rules for [Duplicate Effects](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=312) (listed on that page) state that:

> When you’re affected by the same thing multiple times, only one instance applies, using the higher level of the effects, or the newer effect if the two are the same level.

These are arguably duplicate effects (they do the exact same thing), and thus you'd only get the benefit of one. Whether these feats qualify as effects is a bit unclear, but the [rules on effects](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=350) first example is that simply "[drawing] your sword" qualifies as an effect, so I think that getting these bonuses on Recall Knowledge would also count as an effect. This isn't the most clear-cut RAW, but I'd say the rules strongly lean towards "**No, these don't stack**" - even if they don't count as duplicate effects, it's an easy RAI argument to say "well, Paizo clearly intends to avoid duplicating things, so duplicating feats should not grant double benefits either". Regardless, **ask your GM**.

Comment: As far as I can tell, everything that happens is an 'effect'. It seems to be a catch-all for "not table talk"

Comment: Definitely an ask the GM if I ever get to play the pure knowledgemonkey thaumaturge I want to in the future,  but yeah, I was thinking this might be the case (Especially since it wasn't a numerical bonus like "1 more piece of information:"